# Advice on returning results from a large query returning error- Allowed memory size of 734003200 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to return the result of 3 tables being joined together for a user to download as CSV, and this is throwing the error:

> Allowed memory size of 734003200 bytes exhausted

This is the query being run:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tblProgram`
JOIN `tblPlots` ON `tblPlots`.`programID`=`tblProgram`.`pkProgramID`
JOIN `tblTrees` ON `tblTrees`.`treePlotID`=`tblPlots`.`id`
```

The line of code causing the error is this:

```
$resultsALL=$this->db->query($fullQry);
```

Where $fullQry is the query shown above.  When I comment out that single line, everything runs without the error.  So I'm certain its not an infinite loop somewhere I'm missing.

I'm wondering how do I break up the query so that I can get the results without erroring out? The tables only have a relatively small amount of data in them right now and will be even larger eventually, so I don't think raising the memory size is a good option.

I'm using CodeIgniter/php/mysql.  I can provide more code if need be...

Thank you for any direction you can advise!

Comment: Which version of CodeIgniter are you using?

Comment: I don't know codeigniter but my presumption would be that buffered queries are being used. That commits full result set, use unbuffered if possible and it will only run 1 per row.. you may still run out of memory though if storing all results. Also do you need every column? replacing `*` with columns you need will cut memory consumption.

Comment: I'm on CodeIgniter 3.1.11

Comment: I would like to provide all fields if possible- this is for a user to download available data.  I actually have tried just pulling a few fields and still get the out of memory error, though.

Comment: @xanabobana CodeIgniter 3 uses [$this->db->query("YOUR QUERY")->unbuffered_row()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html?highlight=buffer#CI_DB_result::unbuffered_row)

Comment: [Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted + mysql + php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585999/allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-mysql-php)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa I tried using $dbquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) and unbuffered_row() but still receive the same out of memory error :(  there has to be a way to do this!

Comment: @xanabobana Okay. Thanks for the feedback. Please give my second answer a second look. I fixed the  "temporary table not persisting" issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off of: [MySQL : retrieve a large select by chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34180941)

You may also try retrieving the data in chunks by using the [`LIMIT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/limit/) clause.

Since you're using CodeIgniter 3, here is how you can go about it.

You may need to pass a different `$orderBy` *argument#6* to the `getChunk(...)` method if in case your joined tables have conflicting `id` column names.

I.e: `$this->getChunk(..., ..., ..., 0, 2000, "tblProgram.id");`

##### Solution:

```php
<?php

class Csv_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $sql = <<< END
SELECT *
FROM `tblProgram`
JOIN `tblPlots` ON `tblPlots`.`programID`=`tblProgram`.`pkProgramID`
JOIN `tblTrees` ON `tblTrees`.`treePlotID`=`tblPlots`.`id`
END;

        $this->getChunk(function (array $chunk) {
            /*
             * Do something with each chunk here;
             * Do something with each chunk here;
             * log_message('error', json_encode($chunk));
             * */
        }, $this->db, $sql);
    }

    /*
     * Processes a raw SQL query result in chunks sending each chunk to the provided callback function.
     * */
    function getChunk(callable $callback, $DBContext, string $rawSQL = "SELECT 1", int $initialRowOffset = 0, int $maxRows = 2000, string $orderBy = "id")
    {
        $DBContext->query('DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS chunkable');
        $DBContext->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE chunkable AS ( $rawSQL ORDER BY `$orderBy` )");

        do {

            $constrainedSQL = sprintf("SELECT * FROM chunkable ORDER BY `$orderBy` LIMIT %d, %d", $initialRowOffset, $maxRows);
            $queryBuilder = $DBContext->query($constrainedSQL);
            $callback($queryBuilder->result_array());
            $initialRowOffset = $initialRowOffset + $maxRows;

        } while ($queryBuilder->num_rows() === $maxRows);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I get an error that the table chunkable does not exist on the first SELECT * FROM chunkable.  Why isn't the temporary table persisting long enough to run that select on it?

Comment: @xanabobana Sorry for the bug! I didn't run into it until today. Anyways the fix is quite simple. Check my edited answer. I simply changed `->simple_query(...)` to `->query(...)` Let me know if that works for you. Good luck!

Comment: thanks @steven7mwesigwa.  I get the error "Access denied for user 'vmc_writer'@'%' to database 'VMC_nefin'" now when trying to create the table.  I tried to grant privileges in phpmyadmin using "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO  'vmc_writer'@'%';GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON *.* TO  'vmc_writer'@'%';" but I get "Access denied for user 'vmc_admin'@'%' (using password: YES)"  Does this mean I need to ask the db admin for different privileges?

Comment: @xanabobana Yes. Most specifically `GRANT CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ON *.* TO 'vmc_writer'@'%';`

Comment: @xanabobana That command needs to be run by a MySQL/MariaDB user account that has the ability to **grant privileges**.

Answer (score 0):

> Use `getUnbufferedRow()` for processing large result sets.

[`getUnbufferedRow()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#getUnbufferedRow)

> This method returns a single result row without prefetching the whole
> result in memory as `row()` does. If your query has more than one row,
> it returns the current row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

```php
$query = $db->query("YOUR QUERY");

while ($row = $query->getUnbufferedRow()) {
    echo $row->title;
    echo $row->name;
    echo $row->body;
}
```

> For use with MySQLi you may set MySQLi’s result mode to
> `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` for maximum memory savings. Use of this is not
> generally recommended but it can be beneficial in some circumstances
> such as writing large queries to csv. If you change the result mode be
> aware of the tradeoffs associated with it.

```php
$db->resultMode = MYSQLI_USE_RESULT; // for unbuffered results

$query = $db->query("YOUR QUERY");

$file = new \CodeIgniter\Files\File(WRITEPATH.'data.csv');

$csv = $file->openFile('w');

while ($row = $query->getUnbufferedRow('array'))
{
    $csv->fputcsv($row);
}

$db->resultMode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT; // return to default mode
```

##### Note:

> When using `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` all subsequent calls on the same
> connection will result in error until all records have been fetched or
> a `freeResult()` call has been made. The `getNumRows()` method will
> only return the number of rows based on the current position of the
> data pointer. MyISAM tables will remain locked until all the records
> have been fetched or a `freeResult()` call has been made.

> You can optionally pass ‘object’ (default) or ‘array’ in order to
> specify the returned value’s type:

```php
$query->getUnbufferedRow();         // object
$query->getUnbufferedRow('object'); // object
$query->getUnbufferedRow('array');  // associative array
```

[`freeResult()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#freeResult)

> It frees the memory associated with the result and deletes the result
> resource ID. Normally PHP frees its memory automatically at the end of
> script execution. However, if you are running a lot of queries in a
> particular script you might want to free the result after each query
> result has been generated in order to cut down on memory consumption.

```php
$query = $thisdb->query('SELECT title FROM my_table');

foreach ($query->getResult() as $row) {
    echo $row->title;
}

$query->freeResult(); // The $query result object will no longer be available

$query2 = $db->query('SELECT name FROM some_table');

$row = $query2->getRow();
echo $row->name;
$query2->freeResult(); // The $query2 result object will no longer be available
```

Comment: Thank you!  Unfortunately I still got the same error when I tried this.